# Maximum likelihood estimation for a sequence of observations

Tags: self-study, estimation, maximum-likelihood, random-variable, exponential-distribution

Assuming $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ are independent exponential random variables (each having the same parameter and, for the sake of simplicity, let's assume the value of the parameter is 1).
Define $B_i = A_i + k$  (where $k$ is a constant of unknown value).

What would the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) of $k$ be, if we're also provided with  a sequence of observations $(b_1, b_2,\ldots, b_n)$?

Comment: If this is a self-study question, please add the self-study tag.

Comment: For some intuition--and a generalization--note that over its support $[0,\infty),$ the exponential PDF strictly decreases. Let us assume only that the $A_i$ are independent variables having *any* distributions on $[0,\infty)$ (possibly varying among the $(A_i)$) whose PDFs strictly decrease. Nevertheless (1) the MLE cannot exceed any of the $b_i$, making $\min\{b_i\}$ a lower bound for the MLE, while (2) decreasing $k$ increases *every one* of the probabilities of the $b_i$, thereby increasing the likelihood. Now draw the (only possible) conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, $B_i$ is a shifted/non-central exponential distribution with location parameter $k$.  So write the joint density $$f(\boldsymbol b \mid k) = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-(b_i - k)} \boldsymbol 1[b_i > k].$$  Do a little algebra and write the log-likelihood $\ell(k \mid \boldsymbol b)$.

Comment: Because I misinterpreted the question to be $B_i = A_i + ki$ instead of just $k$.  I will edit.

Comment: thanks a lot for the pdf;  I eventually got to the right answer (which was also suggested by @whuber)