# MLE of exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

> Let $Y\sim Exp(1)$  and $T=\mu+Y,\ \mu\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $t_1,\dots,t_n$ be a simple random sample from $T$ with $\mu$ unknown parameter.
>   How can I find MLE for $\mu$?

I know that the likelihood function is:

$$L(\mu;t)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(e^{-t}+\mu\right)$$

I'm stuck on this expression so I'm not able to find log-likelihood and google can't help :-)

**Edit**

Thanks to Glen I understand my initial mistake. I found CDF $P(Y\leq t-\mu)=F_Y(t;\mu)=1-e^{-t+\mu}$ and hence its density $f_Y(t;\mu)=e^{-t+\mu}$.

I've made some research and found that this is a shifted exponential [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99281/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-a-sequence-of-observations/99288#99288) and [here](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/nonstandard_methods.pdf).

Comment: Your likelihood function is incorrect (or perhaps you made a typo in writing up the MahJax/LaTeX). What's the density of $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$P(T\leq t) = P(T-\mu\leq t-\mu) = P(Y\leq t-\mu)$

Hence you should be able to write down the CDF of $T$ by inspection, and hence its density.

From there, you should be able to write down the likelihood function for $\mu$ (and as easily, the log-likelihood).

You need to be careful about the domain of the likelihood function. If you are careful about it, the MLE should be obvious.

If you can't see it immediately, it may help to start with $n=1$ or $n=2$ and actually *draw* the likelihood function.

Comment: Hi, I understand my initial mistake. I found CDF $P(Y\leq t-\mu)=F_Y(t;\mu)=1-e^{-t+\mu}$ and hence its density $f_Y(t;\mu)=e^{-t+\mu}$. I've made some research and found that this is a shifted exponential [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99281/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-a-sequence-of-observations/99288#99288) and [here](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/nonstandard_methods.pdf)

Comment: Certainly it's shifted exponential; your original definition takes an exponential ($Y$) and shifts it (by $\mu$, giving $T=Y+\mu$); that's just what the term "shifted exponential" means. Were you able to figure out the MLE?

Comment: I found that MLE for $\mu$ is $\hat\mu=t_{(1)}$ and also that $\mu$ should be lower or equal to $t$ otherwise the likelihood is zero.