# What is the MLE of $\boldsymbol{\theta}=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ for the random sample from $f(x|\boldsymbol{\theta})$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let there be a random sample $X_1,\cdots,X_n \sim f(x|\boldsymbol{\theta})=\frac{1}{\theta_2}exp[\frac{-(x-\theta_1)}{\theta_2}], x > \theta_1, -\infty<\theta_1<\infty,0<\theta_2<\infty$. How can I find the MLE of $\boldsymbol{\theta}=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$?

**My work:**

$L(\boldsymbol{\theta})=\frac{1}{\theta_2^n}exp[\frac{-1}{\theta_2}\sum(x_i-\theta_1)]1_{\{\theta_1,\infty\}}(x_{(1)})$

$log(L(\boldsymbol{\theta}))=l(\boldsymbol{\theta})=-nlog(\theta_2)-\frac{1}{\theta_2}(\sum (x_i)-n\theta_1)+log(1_{\{\theta_1,\infty\}}(x_{(1)}))$

$\frac{\partial l(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \theta_2}=\frac{-n}{\theta_2}-\frac{\sum(x_i)-n\theta_1}{\theta_2^2}=0$ implies that $\hat{\theta_1}=-\frac{(n+\sum x_i)}{n}$

$\frac{\partial l(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \theta_1}=\frac{n}{\theta_2}+\frac{1}{1_{\{\theta_1,\infty\}}(x_{(1)})}=0$

Where do I go from here? I do not think that I did the second partial derivative correctly for $\theta_1$.

**Updated work based on provided link to show $lnL(\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma}) > lnL(\mu,\sigma), \forall (\mu,\sigma)$:**

So, $\hat{\theta_1}=X_{(1)}$ and $\hat{\theta_2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum(x_i-x_{(1)})$

$lnL(\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma}) > lnL(\mu,\sigma)$

$(\frac{n}{\sum(x_i-x_{(1)})})^nexp[\frac{-n}{\sum(x_i-x_{(1)})}\sum(x_i-x_{(1)})]>\frac{1}{\theta_2^n}exp[\frac{-1}{\theta_2}\sum(x_i-\theta_1)]$

$(\frac{n\theta_2}{\sum(x_i-x_{(1)})})^nexp[\frac{-n}{\sum(x_i-x_{(1)})}\sum(x_i-x_{(1)})+\frac{1}{\theta_2}\sum(x_i-\theta_1)]>1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MLE for 2 parameter exponential distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298874/mle-for-2-parameter-exponential-distribution)

Comment: @corey979  - no, it doesn't; see the OP's comment in response to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution is just the two parameter exponential distribution.  I found a discussion here:

[MLE for 2 parameter exponential distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298874/mle-for-2-parameter-exponential-distribution)

Comment: The posts look similar, but in their example: $x \ge \mu$, whereas for this problem, $x > \theta_1$. So, $\hat{\theta_1}_{MLE} \ne X_{(1)}$, which change the problem entirely, right?

Comment: @Edison - try plotting (by hand will do) the likelihood function for $\theta_1$ with the simplified problem with $\theta_2 = 1$ and a single observation of $x=1$.  Does the likelihood function actually have a maximum?  Or is it rather a supremum which is never actually attained?  What does this say about whether an MLE exists?

Comment: @Edison '$x>\theta_1$' and '$x\ge \theta_1$' are often used interchangeably and makes no difference in practice ($P(X=\theta_1)=0$). Only mathematically MLE does not exist in the strict inequality case. See the answers and comments in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/391612/119261) thread.

Comment: @StubbornAtom - But this is a mathematical question, and "The MLE does not exist because of the use of the $\geq$ symbol instead of $>$" is what I'd hope a student would answer, give or take some wording, on a math stat class assignment.

Comment: @jbowman It's just that as a student I haven't yet come across a professor who writes the $>$ symbol deliberately so that the non-existence of MLE is argued by the student. More often than not they use '$>$' and '$\ge $' interchangeably in densities and expect the usual answer.

Comment: @StubbornAtom - hmmm, good point.  Edison may well have caught a small sloppiness on the part of the professor rather than an intentional tricky question.

Comment: @jbowman So, if I were to use $\ge$ explicitly, the MLE does not exist? How could you argue that?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I will clarify this question with my professor this week. Assuming that she meant $>$ rather than $\ge$, I still don't know how to explicitly show that $lnL(\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma}) > lnL(\mu,\sigma) \forall (\mu,\sigma)$. I assume that I need not compare the indicator functions for either log likelihood. I updated my post with some work. How do you suggest that I proceed?

Comment: If you use $>$ explicitly, the MLE becomes "the largest number < $X_{(1)}$", which doesn't exist.  Sorry, in my comment above I switched $>$ and $\geq$, thus strongly supporting @StubbornAtom 's point, ironically.

Comment: @jbowman after speaking with my professor, she stated that she meant to type $\ge$ rather than $>$, but I'm glad I was able to engage in this conversation with you and...

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Thank you for all of your continuous help on this forum!

Comment: Gameoverman - if you edit your answer, I can remove my downvote, since you actually gave the right answer!  (But you have to edit it or I can't.)

Comment: @jbowman edited